# Firebase Web 2.4.0 Promises in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am having some issues with error callbacks from Firebase Web in a Node application.

The original issue was that the error callback from a .set was apparently not being fired when I expected it to be.

In the process of debugging, I upgraded the  Firebase npm module to the latest 2.4.0 (NodeJS 0.10.28) and then noticed that there is a new Promise syntax for the asynchronous calls.

I didn't find an example of using the new syntax, but made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpgarrod/66cub4fk/) and it seems to work in the way I expected in the browser.

```
var fb = new Firebase("https://katowulf-examples.firebaseio.com/");

// monitors changes and updates UI
try {
  fb.child('sorted_widgets').orderByChild('name').equalTo('one').once('value').then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError)
  fb.child(undefined).once('value').then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError)
  fb.child('sorted_widgets').set(undefined).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError)

} catch (err) {
  console.error('Caught an error', err)
}

function handleSuccess(snap) {
  console.log('snap: ', snap.val())
}

function handleError(err) {
  console.log('error:', err)
}
```

I am now trying to use that syntax in my Node application and getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<nb> has no method 'catch'
    at myFunction (/node_scripts/my_script.js:514:19)
    at c (/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:238:58)
    at /node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:199:710
    at ec (/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:52:165)
    at ac (/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:31:216)
    at bc (/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:30:1259)
    at Ii.h.Ib (/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:218:287)
    at Qh.h.Jd (/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:185:251)
    at Eh.Jd (/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:175:364)
```

One thing I noticed in fiddling is that not all errors are caught by .catch(). I put the Javascript Try Catch in the fiddle to demonstrate that, but it's really a separate issue.

Given that I am experiencing problems on top of problems, I wondered if there is something wrong with my Node installation, so have reinstalled Node and deleted and reinstalled my node_modules. I'm still not making any progress.

Has anybody got the new Promise syntax working in Node? Any suggestions please?

Comment: Perhaps your version of node doesn't implement the promise `.catch` function, but the browser does. It's tough to say without knowing more about your node setup.

One thing to try is to pull in a separate library for handling promises. Bluebird is a popular one. Try doing `npm install bluebird`, and then at the top of your file that uses promises `Promise = require("bluebird")`.

Comment: You're *very* likely right @AlexKlibisz. Can you provide that as an answer, so that I can upvote it?

Comment: I am using promises extensively in my code, with 'es6-promise', so I don't think that is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are 3 things going on:

1. node v0.10.28 doesn't come with a builtin implementation of Promise.
2. The firebase module bundles a Promise/A+-compatible implementation that it uses when there isn't already one defined.
3. The implementation we ship with firebase is a pure Promise/A+ implementation and doesn't include `.catch()`.

However `.catch()` is very useful and although not part of Promise/A+ it is semi-standard so we're planning to go ahead and add it to our bundled Promise implementation in an upcoming release, which should resolve your issue.

In the meantime, you could do any of the following:

- Use `.then(null, function(err) { ... })` instead of `.catch(function(err) { ... })`
- Import a suitable Promise implementation into your environment.  E.g. `global.Promise = require('rsvp').Promise;`
- Upgrade to node v0.12.x or newer, which comes with a builtin Promise implementation (that supports `.catch()`).

Comment: My script had a dependency which bombed with NodeJS > 0.10 so I was unable to upgrade but I see that the Firebase Promise syntax works corrrectly with a more 'modern' version of Node. Thanks Michael!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase uses the underlying Promise implementation when that's available. It looks like the Promises implementation in your node environment doesn't support `catch()`, which is not required.

Since this:

```
.then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError)
```

is just a different notation for:

```
.then(handleSuccess, handleError)
```

You can go with the latter to get it working.

Comment: Please see my comment above. I am using es6-promise extensively, which certainly supports. catch

Comment: Firebase only checks compatibility with the A+ spec, which didn't have a `catch()` yet. It's likely the promise you get back on nodejs is a [`goog.Promise`](https://closure-library.googlecode.com/git-history/docs/class_goog_Promise.html).

Comment: I can confirm that the alternative notation you suggested works (unlike bluebird answer above). However, I think it's reasonable to expect the Promise to work according to the ECMAScript 2015 standard, so I feel this is a bug.

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/blog/2016-01-21-keeping-our-promises.html "Our promises are A+ compatible"

Comment: And then goes on to say that Firebase supports a 'shorthand catch', which is what I have used. The npm page also says that the node library has 'the same javascript api as the web client'. That appears to be untrue.

Comment: Sorry kpg, that's my fault. I added catch to the return type of Firebase.push() which involved some dirty hacking, but missed that our polyfill has a `thenCatch` instead of `catch`. We'll release an update. In the meantime you can use `.then(null, onRejected)`.

Answer (score 0):

A copy of my initial comment:

Perhaps your version of node doesn't implement the promise .catch function, but the browser does. It's tough to say without knowing more about your node setup.

One thing to try is to pull in a separate library for handling promises. Bluebird is a popular one. Try doing npm install bluebird, and then at the top of your file that uses promises Promise = require("bluebird").

Some more information:

I see now you are using the es6-promises polyfill. Again, I don't know enough about your node/transpiling setup to be definitive. A guess would be that it is possible that the Firebase sdk source would need to be transpiled with the polyfill for it to take effect for the sdk. So it may still be worth temporarily pulling in bluebird as a sanity check.

Comment: @kpg Yeah, I can confirm I'm now having the same problem. Transpiling with Babel 6 and it fails when trying to do async/await via promises. I've been using the fireproof module without any problems for a while now so I will stick with that for some time. https://github.com/casetext/fireproof