# Firebase ES6 promises documentation

Tags: javascript, firebase

I understand from this post [Firebase Web 2.4.0 Promises in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964342/firebase-web-2-4-0-promises-in-nodejs) that Firebase now support ES6 promises. However I cannot find any other references to it.

Does there exist any documentation of the ES6 promises syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time there is no documentation on the main site, [but the introductory blog post is quite comprehensive](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2016-01-21-keeping-our-promises.html), and contains a table for every function in the API.